# Error" num2str: PRECISION must be a scalar integer >= 0"

Tags: octave

I am trying to execute a function ,it works as intended until line 83 where it is

`disp(['The current root at the ', num2str(k),'-th iterate is ', num2str(p1, 10.5)]);`

Here is my actual code:

```
function newton(p)

Delta=10e-2;
Epsilon=10e-2;
Small=10e-3;
Max=99;

Cond=0;
k=0;

y0=fny(p);

disp(' ');
disp(['Date = ', date]);
disp(['The Newton-Raphson Iteration with Delta=', num2str(Delta), ' , Epsilon=', num2str(Epsilon)...
        ,' and Small=', num2str(Small)]);   
disp(['The maximum number of iterations allowed is ', num2str(Max)]);
disp(' ');



    disp('   k                 p(k)          p(k+1)-p(k)               f(p(k))');
    disp('|---|--------------------|--------------------|---------------------|');

while k<=Max & Cond==0,
       
    [y_, Df]=fny(p);

    if Df==0,
       Cond=1;
       Dp=0;
   else
       Dp=y0/Df;
   end
   
   p1=p-Dp;
   y1=fny(p1);
   
   RelErr=2*abs(Dp)/(abs(p1)+Small);
    
   ds_i=sprintf('%4d %20.10g %20.10g  %20.10g', k, p, abs(p1-p), fny(p));
   disp(ds_i);

   
   if RelErr<Delta & abs(y1)<Epsilon,
       
       if Cond~=1,
           Cond=2;
       end
   end
   
   p=p1;
   y0=y1;
      
k=k+1;

pokis(k)=(p);

end

ds_i=sprintf('%4d %20.10g %20.10g  %20.10g', k, p, p1-p, fny(p));
disp(ds_i);

disp(' ');
disp(['The current root at the ', num2str(k),'-th iterate is ', num2str(p1, 10.5)]);
disp(['Consecutive iterates differ by ', num2str(Dp,10.5)]);
disp(' ');

if Cond==0,
   disp('The maximum number of iteration was exceeded! ');
elseif Cond==1,
    disp('Division by zero was encountered!');
elseif Cond==2,
    disp('The root was found with the disired tolerances!');
end
```

It is working fine in Matlab but i don't know why it is giving me error on Gnu-Octave. I enter it as newton(1) and the graph output is fine but disp functions are not displaying as intended

Comment: Please read [mre]. You post way too much code to illustrate the problem. Also, please clarify why it doesn’t work: error message? (copy-paste the full error message) wrong output? (include actual and expected output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

Replace `num2str` with `mat2str`

Answer (score 2):

without a complete example with inputs and error messages it's tough to be sure what the exact problem is.  However it appears you've stumbled into undocumented Matlab behavior that is incompatible with Octave actually following the documented behavior of `num2str`.  According to the [Matlab function description](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) `precision` must be a positive integer specifying the "maximum number of significant digits in the output string".  Octave has this same stated behavior as per [Octave's function help for num2str](https://octave.org/doc/latest/Converting-Numerical-Data-to-Strings.html).  Despite this stated requirement, Matlab appears to accept a non-integer input for `n`, whereas Octave produces the error your reported. A few quick tests seem to suggest that Matlab applies the `round` function to the value. E.g., in Matlab 2020a:

```
>> num2str(123322,2)
ans =
    '1.2e+05'

>> num2str(123322,3)
ans =
    '1.23e+05'

>> num2str(123322,2.6)
ans =
    '1.23e+05'

>> num2str(123322,2.5)
ans =
    '1.23e+05'

>> num2str(123322,2.4999)
ans =
    '1.2e+05'
```

So I'm not sure what behavior you were hoping to get by specifying `precision = 10.5` in num2str, but it appears you were getting the effect of `precision = 11` in Matlab, but an error in Octave.

Regarding your comment above about 'fixing' the problem by changing to mat2str, while this will likely now work for you in Octave, I expect you will get errors in Matlab if you wanted this to be compatible code.  In Matlab, once again the [help documentation for `mat2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html) states that precision is to be "specified as a positive integer".  This time, Matlab 2020a throws an error:

```
>> mat2str(123322,2.4999)
Error using mat2str (line 51)
Precision must be a positive integer scalar.
```

but while [Octave's function help for mat2str](https://octave.org/doc/latest/Converting-Numerical-Data-to-Strings.html) also says it expects integer inputs, it apparently allows non-integers.  Instead of applying `round`, however it seems to apply `floor`, truncating any decimal part.  E.g., in Octave 5.2.0:

```
>> mat2str(123322,2)
ans = 1.2e+05

>> mat2str(123322,2.4999)
ans = 1.2e+05
    
>> mat2str(123322,2.5)
ans = 1.2e+05

>> mat2str(123322,2.6)
ans = 1.2e+05

>> mat2str(123322,3)
ans = 1.23e+05
```

In short, you've found a workaround that allows your code to run. However, you're going to get a different result in Octave than you had in Matlab.  You were specifying precision = 10.5.  Matlab's `num2str` interprets that as 11.  Octave's `mat2str` interprets that as 10.

I would recommend you instead ask for the actual precision you want, 10 or 11, in which case either program or function would work for this purpose.